# HttpApi Scala PlayFramework Essential Action to Result

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

In my controller using the Action.async Method, I have returned an `EssentialAction`. The Essential Action has the format of `RequestHeader => Array[Byte] => Result`

Is there a way to just get the Result from the Essential Action so I could use the result?

Comment: You'd better move the reusable code as a common function that could be used from your existing action and from elsewhere.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, so there is no way to use an EssentialAction?